# how to create branch-alias for composer and use it?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created repository on packagist with composer.json like that:

```
{
  "name" : "vendor/packagename",
  "description" : "some package",
  "license" : "proprietary",
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {"dev-master" : "v2.0.0-dev"}
    }
}
```

On my local machine i am created composer.json like that:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/packagename" "dev-master"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {"dev-master" : "v2.0.0-dev"}
    }
}
```

When i try to install package from repository using command

```
php composer.phar install
```

I am waiting aliased version (v2.0.0)
But i am get last version instead of aliased version (v2.0.0)
So, i need get aliased version when dev-master is installed.
Why code above does not work? Maybe my aliases understanding is wrong?

Comment: If you are requiring `dev-master` that's the same with this config as setting the version constraint to something like `^2.0.0@dev`. What did you expect instead? Did you expect to get the commit that is referred to by the `v2.0.0` tag?

Comment: @xabbuh What did you expect instead? Did you expect to get the commit that is referred to by the v2.0.0 tag? - Yes. But i my understanding was wrong. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in you included packacge something like this:

```json
{
  "name" : "vendor/packagename",
  "description" : "some package",
  "license" : "proprietary",
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {"dev-master" : "2.0.x-dev"}
    }
}
```

Than you can requre that pack in any other project like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/packagename" "2.0.x-dev"
    },
}
```

in that case "2.0.x-dev" will be redirected to master branch.

This has the benefit, if e.g. master branch is updated to another version, the developer of the package could change the branch-alias to the branch that still contains 2.0.x version.